# Scipy not installing on Pycharm

Tags: python, pip, scipy, pycharm

I have been trying to install SciPy from PyCharm for some time. I have tried using the **in-built package installer**, however it would fail. Also I tried installing as a .whl and running as

```
Pip install scipy-1.7.1-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl
```

and that would fail too. Currently unsure where to move forward from here. I use `Windows 10` and am currently using `Python version 3.10 64 bit`. The error message that is coming up is

```
ERROR: scipy-1.7.1-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, M_TTO. Please add the error message you are getting to your question so people can help you more efficiently.

Comment: `I use Windows 10`, but you are using a `macosx` whl file

Comment: if an answer solves your problem, mark it as "solution", don't add [SOLVED] to the title.

Comment: And if you have you found an answer on your own, [you can post an answer yourself](/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be caused because Scipy is not supporting Python 3.10 (yet). `scipy-1.7.1-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl` is the first wheel that appears on [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/scipy/#files). I suppose that PyCharm got confused, and tried to find a compatible wheel.

You have to wait for a compatible release from the Scipy developers (seems like they are waiting for some issues to be resolved). In the meantime, you can try a lower Python version (what about Python 3.9?)

Comment: This was it! Thank you!

Comment: Well, if this was useful, feel free to mark the post as an answer :)